# How to upgrade a custom Ubuntu installation without installing any default applications like Unity?

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-minimal, personalization

I make a choice to install Ubuntu using an alternate CD/DVD with the minimal installation option. After that I run a shell script that will install my favourite desktop environment and applications.

Now it's time to upgrade my Ubuntu version to a new one. But I think that if I do so,  that the Ubuntu upgrade procedure will install Unity and many other Ubuntu applications that I don't like and don't need.

Is there a way to not allow the upgrade script to install any Ubuntu default applications, just upgrade the core and my already installed applications?

Comment: @ProBackup: Abbreviations are not allowed?

Comment: I haven't got any idea whether the is an abbreviation policy or not. For me as a non native speaker, abbreviations are much harder to read and to understand the message.

Comment: I see & I understand :)  BTW I'm not a native speaker too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to upgrade just fine by replacing your current distro name in /etc/apt/sources.list with the next version and doing a full upgrade.

Comment: Nice idea.. But the question is.. Will my Ubuntu crash or upgrade to the next version :D
And can't find out hte answer if we don't try it.. And that's exactly what I'm doing right now :) :D { Hope that my Ubuntu won't crash XD }

Btw that'll be like a trick to have a rolling release..

Comment: It works :D There was some errors in the 2 first days.. But now after many software upgrades I have my 12.04 :D Thx :)

Comment: This solution still valid for upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04?